# Serilog Net Core 3.1 not create any log files

Tags: file, asp.net-core, iis, logging, serilog

I have in .NET Core 3.1 project and i am using Serilog for log management.
This project is deployed on a windows server under IIS. In addition, I have a file server available for storing log files. The IIS user has read and write permissions on this file server, as there are already other web applications that log on this server.
The servers are visible and reachable between them.

I implemented Serilog in the following way:

```
public class Program 
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) 
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
                {
                    // Here I recover the configuration correctly
                    var configuration = GetConfiguration();
                })
                .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => 
                {
                     // hostingContext.Configuration.GetLogOuput() is a custom extension methods.
                     var pathLogFile = Path.Combine(hostingContext.Configuration.GetLogOutput(), hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationName, "concurrentFlat.json");

                    if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        loggerConfiguration
                          .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                          .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                          .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                          .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
                          .Enrich.WithProcessId()
                          .Enrich.WithProcessName()
                          .Enrich.WithThreadId()
                          .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationName)
                          .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName)
                          .WriteTo.Console()
                          .WriteTo.File(
                              path: pathLogFile,
                              formatter: new CompactJsonFormatter(),
                              rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                              fileSizeLimitBytes: 10000000
                          );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        loggerConfiguration
                             .MinimumLevel.Information()
                             .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                             .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                             .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
                             .Enrich.WithProcessId()
                             .Enrich.WithProcessName()
                             .Enrich.WithThreadId()
                             .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationName)
                             .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName)
                             .WriteTo.File(
                                 path: pathLogFile,
                                 formatter: new CompactJsonFormatter(),
                                 rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                                 fileSizeLimitBytes: 10000000
                             );
                    }
                });
}
```

With the development configuration everything works correctly and when I try to simulate the behavior of the application, always on my local machine, in the production environment (setting the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Production) the behavior is the expected one.
This method: "hostingContext.Configuration.GetLogOutput()" reads the path to the file server from an environment variable. I have verified that it is correct, but no files are created.

Here is a code snippet in which I use the .NET Core ILoggger interface:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<FooController> _logger;

    public FooController(ILogger<FooController> logger) 
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Get() 
    {
        _logger.LogError("Test Error log");
         return Ok();
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea why the log file is not created on the file server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "The IIS user has read and write permissions on this file server", which user? Please be specific.

Comment: Is an ad hoc created user who has write and read permissions on both servers. He is a pre-existing user.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and seemed work quite well. So, you can check the list below to see if anything different from mine,

1. package **version**

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Process" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

2. use trivial log path to replace with **pathLogFile** variable for testing

```cs
public static class CustomConfigurationExtension
{
    public static string GetLogOutput(this IConfiguration config) => "log";
}
```

3. setup trivial **appsettings.json** path for different environment (`Development`, `Production`, etc) for testing

Startup.cs

```cs
.ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
{
    config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
})
```

4. use this appsetting.json for testing

appsettings.json

```js
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Most samples above I just followed the **serilog** [EarlyInitializationSample](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/tree/dev/samples/EarlyInitializationSample) in github. Here is the whole things I tested. Hope helps.

Program.cs

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
        })
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
        {
            var pathLogFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                hostingContext.Configuration.GetLogOutput(), 
                hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationName,
                "concurrentFlat.json"
            );

            if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                loggerConfiguration
                  .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                  .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                  .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                  .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
                  .Enrich.WithProcessId()
                  .Enrich.WithProcessName()
                  .Enrich.WithThreadId()
                  .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationName)
                  .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName)
                  .WriteTo.Console()
                  .WriteTo.File(
                      path: pathLogFile,
                      rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                      formatter: new CompactJsonFormatter(),
                      rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                      fileSizeLimitBytes: 10000000
                  );
            }
            else
            {
                loggerConfiguration
                     .MinimumLevel.Information()
                     .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                     .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                     .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
                     .Enrich.WithProcessId()
                     .Enrich.WithProcessName()
                     .Enrich.WithThreadId()
                     .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationName)
                     .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName)
                     .WriteTo.File(
                         path: pathLogFile,
                         formatter: new CompactJsonFormatter(),
                         rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                         fileSizeLimitBytes: 10000000
                     );
            }
        });
```